# How to easily display multiple columns in the console with curses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-columns, ncurses, python-curses

I would like to print data in the console in multiple columns with curses. What is an easy approach to do so?

Currently, my application prints information like this:

```
import curses
(...)
# create default screen
std_scr = curses.initscr()
(...)
# example
for line in lines:
    std_scr.addstr(line + "\n")
std_scr.refresh()
```

This results in the following output

```
line 1
line 2
...
line n
```

However, what I would like to have, is something like this:

```
columns = 3
for line in lines:
   # easy way to separate columns
```

Which should result in:

```
line 1         | line 11          | line 21
line 2         | line 12          | line 22
...            | ...              | ...
line 10        | line 20          | line 30
```

What is an easy way to achieve this? Should I simply use an iterator to iterate in a order like `line 1`, `line 11`, `line 21`, `line 2`, `line 12`, `line 22`, `line 3`, and so forth, while using `line.ljust(30, " ")` to get the whitespaces?

Or should I create multiple screens in curses?

Do other, even simpler solutions exist?

I'm pretty new to curses, thus any general advice + example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I would get the screen dimensions using [`std_scr.getmaxyx`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.getmaxyx), and divide the screen-width by the number of columns.  Also, get the number of lines in each column from the limit on your iterator.  Use [`addnstr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.addnstr) to print the messages (and compute the y,x pair of coordinates for each call to `addnstr` based on the number of columns and lines in your example).